# A problem about extensions of division rings

Tags: rt.representation-theory, associative-algebras, division-algebras

For a division ring $D$ with center field $F:=Z(D)$ such that $\dim_F D = n^2$, there is a classical result saying that $D\otimes_{F}\bar{F}\cong M_n(\bar{F})$ as $\bar{F}$-algebras, where $\bar{F}$ is the algebraic closure of $F$. My question is : If $E$ is a subfield of $F$ suth that $F$ is finite and separable over $E$, is $D\otimes_{E}\bar{F}$ still semisimple?

I already know that this is correct when D is a field.

Comment: You probably assume that $D$ has finite dimension over $F$?

Comment: Oh, yes! I missed this important assumption! Thank you for pointing out it!

Answer (score 2):

I find that the answer of this problem is affirmative and obvious by a trick of tensors:
$D\otimes_{E} \bar{F} \cong (D\otimes_{F}F)\otimes_{E} \bar{F}\cong D\otimes_{F}(F\otimes_{E} \bar{F})\cong D\otimes_{F}\bar{F}^m\cong (D\otimes_{F}\bar{F})^m$.